# Time and Space Complexity(for specific algorithm)

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

Despite the last 30 minutes i spent on trying to understand time and space complexity better, i still can't confidently determine those for the algorithm below:

```
bool checkSubstr(std::string sub)
{
    //6 OR(||) connected if statement(checks whether the parameter
    //is among the items in the list)
}

void checkWords(int start,int end)
{
    int wordList[2] ={0};
    int j = 0;

    if (start < 0)
    {
        start = 0;
    }
    if (end>cAmount)
    {
        end = cAmount -1;
    }
    if (end-start < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= end-2; i++)
    {
        if (crystals[i] == 'I' || crystals[i] == 'A')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (checkSubstr(crystals.substr(i,3)))
        {
            wordList[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (j==1)
    {
        crystals.erase(wordList[0],3);
        cAmount -= 3;
        checkWords(wordList[0]-2,wordList[0]+1);
    }
    else if (j==2)
    {
        crystals.erase(wordList[0],(wordList[1]-wordList[0]+3));
        cAmount -= wordList[1]-wordList[0]+3;
        checkWords(wordList[0]-2,wordList[0]+1);
    }

}
```

The function basically checks a sub-string of the whole string for predetermined (3 letter, e.g. "SAN") combinations of letters. Sub-string length can be 4-6 no real way to determine, depends on the input(pretty sure it's not relevant, although not 100%).

My reasoning:

If there are n letters in the string, worst case scenario, we have to check each of them. Again depending on the input, this can be done 3 ways.

1. All 6 length sub-strings: If this is the case the function runs n/6 times, each running 8(or 10?) processes, which(i think) means that its time complexity is O(n).
2. All 4 length sub-strings: Pretty much the same reason above, O(n).
3. 4 and 6 length sub-strings mixed: Can't see why this would be different than previous 2. O(n)

As for the space complexity, i am completely lost. However, i have an idea:
If the function recurs for maximum amount of time,it will require:
n/4 x The Amount Used In One Run
which made me think it should be O(n). Although, i'm not convinced this is correct. I thought maybe seeing someone else's thought process on this example would help me understand how to calculate time and space complexity better.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Let me provide clearer information. We read a combination of 6 different letters into a string, this can be (almost)any combination in any length. 'crystals' is the string, and we are looking for 6 different 3 letter combinations in that list of letters. Sort of like a jewel matching game. Now the starting list contains no matches(none of the 6 predetermined combinations exist in the first place). Therefore the only way matches can occur from then on is by swaps or matches disappearing. Once a swap is processed by top level code, the function is called to check for matches, and if a match is found the function recurs after deleting the "match" part of the string.

Now let's look at how the code is looking for a match. To demonstrate a swap of 2 letters:

ABA B-R ZIB(no spaces or '-' in the actual string, used for better demonstration),

B and R is being swapped. This swap only effects the 6 letters starting from 2nd letter and ending on 7th letter. In other words, the letters the first A and last B can form a match with are same, before and after the swap, thus no point checking for matches including those words. So a sub-string of 6 letters sent to the checking algorithm. Similarly, if a formed match disappears(gets deleted from the string) the range of effected letters is 4. So when i thought of a worst case scenario, i imagined either 1 swap creating a whole chain reaction and matching all the way till there are not enough letters to form a match, or each match happens with a swap. Again, i am not saying this is how we should think when calculating time and space complexity but this is how the code works. Hope this is clear enough if not let me know and i can provide more details. It's also important to note that swap amount and places are a part of the input we read.

EDIT: Here is how the function is called on top level for the first time:
`checkWords(swaps[i]-2,swaps[i]+3);`

Comment: How can the substring length be part of the input? It seems to be hardcoded into the algorithm: `if (checkSubstr(crystals.substr(i,3))) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

> Sub-string length can be 4-6 no real way to determine, depends on the
>   input (pretty sure it's not relevant, although not 100%).

That's not what the code shows; the line `if (checkSubstr(crystals.substr(i,3)))` conveys that substrings always have exactly 3 characters. If the substring length varies, it is relevant, since your naive substring match will degrade to `O(N*M)` in the general case, where `N` is `start-end+1` (the size of the input string) and `M` is the size of the substring being searched. This happens because in the worst case you'll compare `M` characters for each of the `N` characters of the source string.

The rest of this answer assumes that substrings are of size 3, since that's what the code shows.

If substrings are always 3 characters long, it's different: you can essentially assume `checkSubstr()` is `O(1)` because you will always compare at most 3 characters. The bulk of the work happens inside the for loop, which is `O(N)`, where `N` is `end-1-start`.

After the loop, in the worst case (when one of the `if`s is entered), you erase a bunch of characters from `crystal`. Assuming this is a string backed by an array in memory, this is an `O(cAmount)` operation, because all elements after `wordList[0]` must be shifted. The recursive call always passes in a range of size 4; it does not grow nor shrink with the size of the input, so you can also say there are `O(1)` recursive calls.

Thus, time complexity is `O(N+cAmount)` (where `N` is `end-1-start`), and space complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i added clearer information on how the code works, if you would like to check.

Comment: @user3402183 Looks good. I understood the code. My answer remains the same.

Comment: I see, thank you for helping me. There is a slight issue in my mind with your answer. It is clear, and i understand what you mean, but logically, i can't seem to be able to accept it. Maybe when you have time you could explain it further, meanwhile i will keep researching.

Comment: @user3402183 is there something in particular you don't understand, or you just find it hard to believe it's linear? I can give it a try and improve my answer tomorrow.

Comment: I am confused how we determine the space complexity. Other than that, when i thought about it i came up with a time complexity of O(cn), n being the amount of letters in the string and c is a coefficient with a value around 4-6. Even though i'm sure my math is not 100% accurate, i don't understand where my logic is incorrect. Also, as far as i could understand, when we state complexity, we can ignore constants and coefficients as long as they are not significantly large. So i simplified it to O(n) with n being the number of characters in the string.